# DataTables RowGroup not grouping properly

Tags: datatables

I've got a table that I want to be able to group by different columns, based on User Input. I've started using the RowGroup plugin since this is pretty much exactly what I was looking for, and also found a way to expand/collapse the groupings.

My issue is that for one of the specific groupings, the grouping mechanic doesn't actually function properly, and creates multiple groups when I believe it shouldn't be doing so. The data comes in from the server, so I'm able to apply a .trim() function on the strings in the selected column for grouping.

Below is a link to a copy of my table with the DataTables code that I have implemented, with the only difference being that my version of DataTables is actually 1.10.16, whereas the version used here is 1.10.21-dev - Since I copied in the rest of the code and it worked the same way, I opted to leave the version as it was.

http://live.datatables.net/layudizi/1/edit

If you swap between dataSrc: 4 (problem) and dataSrc: 0 (working properly) you'll see how when grouping by Column 4 (Customer) it will create multiple groupings with the same Customer Number, but when you group by Column 0 (Item Code) there is one group per code. Have I missed something?

Comment: Some observations, in case they help: If you sort the data by column 5 (Customer), does the `dataSrc: 4` grouping look OK? And if you use `dataSrc: 0` and then sort by column 5 (Customer), what happens to the 2 records where the Item Code is 64410? I think the answer is: In your table, if you use `dataSrc: 4` you also have to sort by that column to get the expected groupings.

Comment: More generally, this means the row grouping is dependent on the applied sort. It should probably be the other way round (like in [this demo](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/row_grouping.html)).

Comment: I appreciate your comments, they are very thought provoking and additionally helpful in further developing my testing techniques. The answer is in fact that the table needs to be ordered by the same column it is being grouped on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You see that effect because of your ordering. If you change the order to column 4 as well, you should see the same result as 0. The row grouping is dictated by the adjacent rows, if you are not ordered by the same column then the result is segmented.

```
dataSrc: 4,
"order" : [[4,'asc']]
```

Comment: This does it, thank you so much! I didn't even think of toying with that.